# Splitting decimal in sql

Tags: sql

I am getting result as decimal in stored procedure. If I am getting result as `123.45`,
I want to split it into `123` and `45`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

use SQL function FLOOR() for getting integer part
and subtract that from the original for the decimal part

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) instead of [FLOOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx).

See section [C. Using ROUND to truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) for trucate, and then subtract that from the original.

*Be aware that using FLOOR on negative numbers might not give you the required result.*

Have a look at this example

```
DECLARE @Dec DECIMAL(12,8)

SET @Dec = -123.45

SELECT FLOOR(@DEc)

select round(@Dec, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
DECLARE @result DECIMAL(8,2) = 123.45

SELECT CAST(round(@result,0) AS FLOAT)
SELECT REPLACE(@result % 1 ,'0.','')
```

OR

```
DECLARE @result decimal(8,2) = 123.45
select PARSENAME(@result, 2) AS LeftSideValue, PARSENAME(@result, 1) AS RightSideValue
```